How to filter and modify a database with data_editor in streamlit
I would like to filter the database through columns, which in this case are 'FT' and 'HT', and then insert in the 'Quota' column ONLY for the filtered data the value present in the text_input: 'average quota', and also when they are removed the filters must remain saved (even those that are eventually made manually for each cell)
furthermore the 'Quota' column must be added to the database, because it is not present in the initial one
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

file = "..."
df = pd.read_excel(file)

df["Quota"]=None

st.sidebar.header("Filter here:")

quota_media=st.text_input("Quota media (es: 1.5)")

def get_filterable_columns(df):
    yes_columns = ['HT','FT']  # Aggiungi qui le colonne che non vuoi filtrare
    return [col for col in df.columns if col  in yes_columns]
for col in get_filterable_columns(df):
    if st.sidebar.toggle(f"{col}"):
        if col=="HT" or col=="FT":
            selected_values = st.sidebar.multiselect(f"Seleziona i valori per {col}:",df[col].unique())
            if selected_values:
                df = df[df[col].isin(selected_values)]
                if st.button("Aggiorna Database"):
                    if quota_media:
                        df[ "Quota"] = quota_media

st.data_editor(df)

I tried this code, but every time I insert a value into the text_input, or modify a cell, the modification is not saved after I filter the database
if I filter the FT column and click the button it inserts the value
but if I remove the filter it deletes the previously entered values
